# laravel email didn't work(email sent but the reset page didn't show )

Tags: php, laravel

//Route as follows:

```
  Route::get('forgotPassword', array('as' => 'forgotPassword', 'uses' => 'RemindersController@getRemind')); 

  Route::post('postRemind', array('as' => 'postReminder', 'uses' => 'RemindersController@postRemind')); 

  Route::get('reset/{token}', array('as' => 'getReset', 'uses' => 'RemindersController@getReset')); 

  Route::post('reset', 'RemindersController@postReset');
```

//reminder.blade.php

```
{{ URL::route('getReset', Session::get('_token')) }}
```

//remindersController

```
public function getReset($token = null)
{
    if (is_null($token)) App::abort(404);

    return View::make('frontend.users.password.reset')->with('token', $token);
}
```

It did send me the email and the url is like this:

```
http://localhost/html5lav/public/user/reset/2LEYtzhB0QXfHJH3eC4hj2UH6VLXJsc3iawk6iAv
```

Howerver, i cannot open it . it shows:

Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException

i wonder why did this happen? Thanks

The following problem is solved . but now the problem is that And once submiting the final reset page ,it show :laravel the password reset token is invalid. the url is like: localhost/html5lav/public/user/reset/, Thanks

Comment: and i have the reset php file in frontend.users.password.reset. It just didn't show the reset page!!! Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change these two line:

```
Route::post('reset/{token}', array(
    'as' => 'getReset',
    'uses' => 'RemindersController@getReset'
)); 
Route::post('reset/{token}', 'RemindersController@postReset');
```

To:

```
Route::get('reset/{token}', array(
    'as' => 'getReset',
    'uses' => 'RemindersController@getReset'
)); 
Route::post('reset', 'RemindersController@postReset');
```

Comment: Yeah,I just did.  it dit show. And once submiting the final reset page ,it show :laravel the password reset token is invalid.                                     the url is like:  http://localhost/html5lav/public/user/reset/W6OwKW9Dyml9jvymvRSQHDjhlKKLa12oEcoIJHBv

Comment: The URL looks OK. Please check the token of URL, is it match with your `users` table's  `remember_token` column?

Comment: Nope, the token in the url is not the same as the one of any user in the database. so do i miss something?

Comment: Please share your `postEmail()` may be the email sending a wrong `token`

Comment: it's in the reminder.blade.php: {{ URL::route('getReset', Session::get('_token')) }},  is this what you want?

Comment: I want the code which is responsible for sending email.

Comment: is the following code?  Sorry , I am a newbie in laravel^-^

Comment: May be the code inside your `public function postRemind(){...}`

Comment: Okay, is that what you want?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97199/discussion-between-smartrahat-and-frank-lee).

Answer (score 1):

Your route responds to POST requests because it is Route::post and not Route::get(). Other problem might be that you are sending to request to a route user/reset/{token} and you might not have such route (though I am not sure, because I don't see the whole routes.php file, maybe the reset/{token} is prefixed).

Comment: Yeah, i have a user as prefix. And i have already alter the question. now the problem is  that once submiting the final reset page ,it show :laravel the password reset token is invalid. the url is like: localhost/html5lav/public/user/reset/…

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

class RemindersController extends Controller {

    /**
     * Display the password reminder view.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function getRemind()
    {
        return View::make('frontend.users.password.remind');
    }

    /**
     * Handle a POST request to remind a user of their password.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function postRemind()
    {

        Password::remind(Input::only('email'), function($message)
        {
            $message->subject('HTML5COL学院密码重置邮件');
        });


        switch ($response = Password::remind(Input::only('email')))
        {
            case Password::INVALID_USER:
                return Redirect::back()->with('error', Lang::get($response));

            case Password::REMINDER_SENT:
                return Redirect::back()->with('status', Lang::get($response));
           //假如忘记密码通知信成功的寄发给用户，则会有一个 status 信息被暂存在 session 内；假如寄发失败的话，则取而代之的会有一个 error 信息被暂存。
        }
    }

    /**
     * Display the password reset view for the given token.
     *
     * @param  string  $token
     * @return Response
     */
    public function getReset($token = null)
    {
        if (is_null($token)) App::abort(404);

        return View::make('frontend.users.password.reset')->with('token', $token);
    }

    /**
     * Handle a POST request to reset a user's password.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function postReset()
    {
        $credentials = Input::only(
             'password', 'password_confirmation', 'token'
        );

        $response = Password::reset($credentials, function($user, $password)
        {
            $user->password = Hash::make($password);

            $user->save();
        });

        switch ($response)
        {
            case Password::INVALID_PASSWORD:
            case Password::INVALID_TOKEN:
            case Password::INVALID_USER:
                return Redirect::back()->with('error', Lang::get($response));

            case Password::PASSWORD_RESET:
                return Redirect::to('/');
        }
    }

}
```